# $y=10x+16$ is an equation of the tangent line, then what is $f'(15)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $y=10x+16$ is an equation of the tangent line to the graph of $f$ at the point (15,166) then what is $f'(15)$

I say that the answer is $f'(15)=0$ because of the derivative constant rule.

Or do I just work backwards from the tangent line equation.

Please help!!!

Comment: There's not really a way to answer that without having more information about $f$.

Comment: @IanColey I made an edit where $f$ is actually $f'(15)$ if that helps

Comment: @JohnBeal: You gave the tangent line equation without specifying at what point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f'(15)$= 10 because thats the gradient

y=mx+c

where m is gradient and since the curve gradient at the point and gradient of tangent are equal

Comment: ok I have never heard of gradient before, if you could elaborate please. Was I just looking for m this whole time?

Comment: no problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope try this

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nt-EolL4JHA

Comment: Gradient is a fancy word for slope.